# Webapps communication

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jetty

I have two webapps:
webapp1
webapp2

Is there a way i can make these two to communicate? For example, say servlet context itself.

I am using jetty to start my webapps.

java -cp xyz x.y.z.JettyBootstrap webapp1.war
java -cp xyz x.y.z.JettyBootstrap webapp2.war

Both webapps resides in the same folder. Is it possible for me to have communication between these two webapps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get two web apps running on the same app server to communicate, but perhaps the easiest is to package them into the same application... EAR. An EAR has an application level classloader from which included web apps derive. You can put some classes into that classloader that will enable your data sharing. The web apps will be able to read/write data using normal Java means.